# Is 12 gb ram enough to run a load test of 10,000 concurrent user's in jmeter through non gui mode on windows 8.1 for an i5 processor?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, ruby-jmeter

What will be the hardware configuration required to run concurrent of 10,000 user's load in jmeter through non-gui mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exact answer for this, but in my experience 10,000 users on a single instance doing anything other than very basic work will be too many.

You should look into setting up distributed testing, so that you have many different injectors. Without knowing anything about your application, I would still want at least 10 instances.

This link should get you started: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

If you have budget for it, any of the cloud based Jmeter services will make it a lot less painless. Blazemeter is one such offering in this area: http://blazemeter.com/